# Hide comments from certain people

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, custom-list, custom-actions

**Scenario:**

I created a custom list and one of the fields is comment field.  Some of the comments have names of individuals  (BTW, they're not negative comments). Those individuals have access to the page and need to see the line items associated with the comments.  But I do not want them to see the comments.

**Question:**

Is there a way for the individuals that have their names in the some of the comments be able to view the line item but not the comment fields if their names are in them?

Comment: You could probably do some JS hack for this, but I'd be deeply concerned about transparency issues, and possible "confidential" information leakage. IMO you should think this the other way around and find another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments would need to be in a separate list to have this sort of control. Each list has its own permissions for the items (not columns) the only other options are to use item level permissions to change who can see each item but your requirement sounds different.